# Unable to start the Kentico application when my computer restarts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I installed Kentico 8.2 on my computer. But every time I turn off my computer and open it again. The Kentico Application never starts. I hope you can help me about my problem.

Comment: What actions are you taking to get it going again after you restart your computer?

Comment: I open kentico using the web browser.

Comment: I`m not sure we can help you until we understand your problem. What do you mean by 'open it again' and 'The Kentico Application never starts.'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not a Kentico issue at all, it's an IIS configuration issue.  By default, IIS is configured to only run a website when it is first accessed manually or continually being used.  If the website is idle and not running and you access it, the application pool kicks up and serves up the website.  If there is idle time of 20 minutes (by default) it will go into a sleep state until it is requested again.  When you restart your computer, IIS is in that sleep state until the website is first requested.

Within IIS you can set a few properties to help you out.  In the Application Pool connected to your website go to the advanced properties of it.  Check the General>Start Mode and ensure it is set to Always Running vs. On Demand.

Secondly, in the same Application Pool set the Process Model>Idle time-out (minutes) to something greater than the default 20 minutes.  This will help only after the website is already running.

Thirdly, in the same Application Pool set the Process Model>Idle time-out action to Suspend.  This will help the website start up faster when it does go to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Is autostart enabled in your IIS?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are valid, but if I remember correctly, there was also an issue with Skype taking up a specific port, if you set to "Run Skype on startup". This prevents some of the IIS services/websites to start. Not sure if that relates to your specific issue, but if you've got Skype installed and set to run on startup, try disabling this and restart your PC to see if it helped.